# ODT with Visual Studio (Oracle 11G)

Tags: oracle, odt

I began with Visual Studio 2010 and installed the ODT 11G. This worked completely fine and allowed me to open Oracle projects (.oradbproj).

I ran into another problem while working on Visual Studio 2015. I thought my problem would be fixed by installing ODT 12. This installed fine, however, I realised after that this was unnecessary.

When I came to open VS 2010 and open my Oracle project, I get the error:

> "The selected file cannot be opened. 'XXX.oradbproj' cannot be opened
>   because its project type (.oradbproj) is not supported by this version
>   of the application. To open it, please use a version that supports
>   this type of project."

I then uninstalled both instances of ODT (11.2 and 12) and proceeded to install 11g. When I opened VS2010 afterwards, I was greeted with the following error:

> "The 'Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio .NET' package did not
>   load correctly. The problem may have been caused by a configuration
>   change or by the installation of another extension. You can get more
>   information by running the application together with the /log
>   parameter on the command line and then examining the following
>   file..."

When I examine this file I get quite a few ERRORS ranging from:

> Access is denied and could not load types: Shims.1_0_0_0.dll &
>   Shims.2_0.dll

-

> OracleVSGPkg.SetSite - Exception Oracle Developer Tools VS Package
>   SetSite Oracle.DataAccess The type initializer for
>   'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand' threw an exception. at
>   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand..ctor() at
>   Oracle.VsDevTools.OracleUILGlobal.Initialize(OracleVSGPkg vsgPkg) at
>   Oracle.VsDevTools.OracleVSGPkg.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsPackage.SetSite(IServiceProvider
>   psp) Additonal Information - Oracle.DataAccess Unable to load DLL
>   'OraOps12.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x8007007E) at
>   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OpsInit.CheckVersionCompatibility(String
>   version) at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleInit.Initialize() at
>   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand..cctor()

-

> SetSite failed for package [Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio
>   .NET]

-

> End package load [Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio .NET]

-

> OracleVSGPkg.SetSite - Exception Oracle Developer Tools VS Package
>   SetSite Oracle.DataAccess The type initializer for
>   'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand' threw an exception. at
>   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand..ctor() at
>   Oracle.VsDevTools.OracleUILGlobal.Initialize(OracleVSGPkg vsgPkg) at

-

> Oracle.VsDevTools.OracleVSGPkg.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsPackage.SetSite(IServiceProvider
>   psp) Additonal Information - Oracle.DataAccess Unable to load DLL
>   'OraOps12.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x8007007E) at
>   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OpsInit.CheckVersionCompatibility(String
>   version) at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleInit.Initialize() at
>   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand..cctor()

-

> SetSite failed for package [Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio
>   .NET]

When I check the "About Microsoft Visual Studio" there is no product "Oracle Developer Tools" listed (there was before) and in my Tools there is an option at the side labelled "Oracle Developer Tools" but when I click on it there are no options, just a single message saying "An error occurred loading this property page."

I've tried endless guides found on this website such as going through my registry, deleting all instances of Oracle and uninstalling all related files, then reinstalling. But that did not work. The rest of the questions seem to be similar, but not the same. All I want is to have Oracle 11.2 installed and all instances of 12 deleted, basically what I had before I installed 12.

I had this problem before and ended up having to revert my PC to factory settings.

Comment: you checked the PATH variables so it points to the old Oracle install?

Comment: In my Environment Variables I have changed my Path pointing to
>D:\app\user%name\product\11.2.0\client_1